# Ideas for a Server Dashboard (SQL/WWW)?

Tags: sql-server, iis, monitoring, dashboard

I manage around 15 WWW/FTP servers, and 23 SQL servers (with varying versions of SQL).  I'd like to develop some sort of dashboard so that I can easily see the servers, make sure they are online, determine how much free space they have (including individual drive space), make sure SQL instances are running and/or IIS is running, store miscellaneous information about them such as which applications are hosted on which servers, and provide quick access to do things like RDP into them.

My question is fairly simple.  What sort of technology should I use to develop this dashboard?  Is there a way I can do it without requiring a client-side portion to be hosted on each server?  I'm mainly familiar with ASP/ColdFusion which is what the majority of our environment is, but I also know enough C++ and C# to get through projects (obviously with a lot of looking up stuff).

Are there any free open source projects that currently offer this functionality?  I'm not big on re-inventing anything when it's already available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question should have probably been asked on serverfault.com not stackoverflow.com.  At any rate, none of the answers provided by users were acceptable.  I did find what seems to be the best possible fit and it's called nagios.  I'm looking more into it and seeing if it's something we could use.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not free, but Redgate has a cool tool called [SQL Monitor 2](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-monitor/) for sql server

Answer (score 0):

"Back in the day..."  There were some free perl scripts gathered under the name "Big Brother".  Sounds draconian, but it was actually pretty simple and standard.  You can probably find the code out there, or look at the commercial version at least for ideas.  The version I dealt with was for Unix-like OSs.

The company has a web site [www.bb4.org](http://www.bb4.org) .  There is also a variation called "Big Sister", [www.bigsister.ch](http://www.bigsister.ch), but I swear I only caught a glimpse in the mirror as I was passing by.  I believe that there are perl modules that will give the same functionality, and if it exists in perl, I imagine that there are plugins for Python or VB or whatever flavor you like.

But I digress...

Back to the dashboards.

It did "is the server up" dashboard with idiot lights, disk space gauges, ping times, etc.  Once you looked at the code, you would know what to do to craft your own pretty much, if you wanted to do something specialized like test SMTP server, get local weather, etc.

The main thing I remember where screens for idiot lights for servers:
For a given list of servers -- red light, green light, yellow light:
 (ping server "xyz", record response, if you get a response, use the green traffic signal.  If the response is slow, use the yellow signal.  If no response in "n" seconds, use the red signal.  Repeat every "n" minutes, for each server in list.)
The disk-space and process charts didn't really give me any real info, and we had SAs at each site.

When I was monitoring an ASP server, I had a scheduled job that ran commands piped to a text file.  First test:  Can I get to the text file?  No?  Server communications are down.

The rest was parsing the result files for patterns, and using that information in a table in HTML.  I didn't use graphics, I just mod'd fonts and attributes.

I hope that helps.